# How to customize TEI scheme / how to add custom attributes to TEI Doc?

Tags: attributes, oxygenxml, tei

I want to use the teiCorpus element/scheme that can be found in Oxygen XML to structure a corpus. Sadly i dont know where to add attributes like `<date>` or `<mediatype>`. I tried to put them into the header or into the body but Oxygen doesn't validate the document because these attributes are not allowed where I put them. I also tried to use something like `<p class="mediatype">` in the body, but the `"class='mediatype'"` doesnt seem to work either. Do I need to change the dtd to make it work or is there an other possibility?

Because I was asked, here is some example code:

```
<teiCorpus xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader>
        ....
    </teiHeader>
    <TEI xml:id="MyTextNumber1">
        <teiHeader>
            <fileDesc>
                <titleStmt>
                </titleStmt>
                <publicationStmt>
                </publicationStmt>
                <sourceDesc>
                </sourceDesc>
            </fileDesc>
        </teiHeader>
        <text>
            <body>
            </body>
        </text>
    </TEI>
</teiCorpus>
```

I want to put custom attributes like "mediatype" or "date" in there, as i would in a normal xml file. I tried nearly every option, but i only get error codes like `"element "date" not allowed here; expected the element end-tag or element ..."`
How do i implement custom attributes in TEI? Is it possible?

Comment: As of now our question is a bit unclear. I think it would help a lot if you'd include some of your code, preferably as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey, @NinoFiliu. Here is the shortest example possible. I just want to add custom attributes like "date" under "titleStmt" or "body" (or any place else). But it doesnt seem possible. I am not coding, but manually editing an TEI file with a XML editor.